# How to bring JLabels in GridBagConstrains at top

Tags: java, swing, position, gridbaglayout

I was trying this code, and for some reason, it appears in the middle. Here's my code:

```
        String errormsg = "Something went wrong."; 
    final String title = "Wall Game";

    this.setSize(400, 500); //sets the screen
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(401,501);
    try {
        Font font1 = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 15);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); //makes all the panels
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Welcome to the Wall Game!"); //labels
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Click the button to read instructions!");
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Start");//buttons
        button1.setText("Start!");
        label1.setFont(font1);
        button1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(button1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,10,10,10);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel1.add(label1, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel1.add(label2, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        panel1.add(button1, gbc);
        this.add(panel1);
    }
    catch(Exception e) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong. Try restarting.", "Sorry", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Where the text shows is in the middle. Not starting from the top. Here's a mini example of what it would look like:

[image]

Does anyone know how to make the starting point from the top? Thanks to anyone who can help. Before you try helping, try the code first. You, will definitely need `import "javax.swing.*"` FYI.

Thumbs up if you like the paint drawing I did lol :D I drew it in Window's paint.

Comment: I shall **excaterate** more, and it's actually more to the bottom.

Comment: you should assign values to gbc.weightx and gbc.weighty (between 0.0 and 1.0 - recommended); this will define how much of the extra space will be assigned to each component; if they weights for x OR y are ALL 0.0 (not set), they will be placed on center. maybe you should also take a look over gbc.anchor (the place where the element should stay), gbc.fill (how it should be stretched) and later on gbc.gridwidth/height..
read the documentation; it will help you :)

Comment: also, if you need help with this, let us know where and how you want the components to be positioned/aligned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBag Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), especially the section on the weightx/y constraints.

You need to have a non-zero value set for one of the components otherwise the components are centered.